# Why is this int not taking up two bytes of my array?

Tags: c, memory

So basically I am really confused as to why when I assign some value of an array to an int is it not taking up two indices within that array.

I have tried to change my code to use pointers/addresses instead of directly setting the array spot to the int, but none of those fix my problem/confusion.

I have declared my array in my header .h file like this
    char arr[4096] = {'\0'};

Then I assign some value of this array to 16.

```
arr[0]=16;
```

Then I test to see how much space in the array 16 (an int) has taken up:

```
        p = 0;
        while(arr[p]!='\0'){
        printf("testing\n");
        p++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",p);
```

However, it always prints 1 for the value of p instead of 2, indicating that only arr[0] is occupied by the int. I am so confused as to how this memory stuff works and how can I get an int to take up two spots of an array in memory. Why is the value 1 instead of 2? And why does the int only take up 1 spot of the array?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a value of type `int` to a member of a `char` array does not take up multiple elements of the array.  Section 6.5.16.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the assignment operator `=` states:

> In simple  assignment(`=`),  **the  value  of  the  right  operand  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the assignment  expression**  and 
>   replaces  the  value  stored  in  the  object  designated  by  the 
>   left operand.

So the `int` value is converted to type `char` before assignment.  And because the value 16 falls in the range of possible values for a `char`, no conversion of the value needs to take place.

If you really want to assign to multiple values of a `char` array like this, the proper way would be to assign the `int` value to an `int` variable and use `memcpy`:

```
int value = 16;
memcpy(&arr[0], &value, sizeof(value));
```

But even then the result would not be any different.  Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes the contents of `value` are `0x00000010`, so only one of the 4 bytes that make up this value contains a value other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to a variable, the value will first be converted to the type of the value. That's just the way C (and basically all other languages) work.

Another thing that might (depending on architecture) the result is that 16 is small enough to fit in one byte. So even if your code were writing to both `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` it's not strange if it wrote 16 to `arr[0]` and 0 to `arr[1]`. So you should use larger numbers in order to be sure to detect something like this.

In order to achieve what you expect, you can do something like this:

```
int *p = (int*) &arr[0];
*p = 12345;
```

But unless you really know what you're doing, you should not do stuff like that. It's very tricky to get it right.

Also, the usual size for `int` is 4 and not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Because 16 is cast down to char and it is placed only in the first cell. This is a reason why you always have 1.
If you try to set 16 as a pattern for few elements, eg:

```c
memset(&arr[0], 16, 4);
```

or set bigger value (i have 4 bytes int)

```c
*(int*)arr = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

then you have got 4 spaces different than `'\0'`.